# Scaling specific containers inside pods

Tags: kubernetes

i am relatively new to `kubernetes` and i am trying to catch things, in my understanding, a `pod` can have `single` container as well as `multiple` containers. Lets say i have a `pod` with `5` tightly coupled containers and is it possible to `autoscale` only `2` of them based on the `usage`. or `autoscale` will only happen `pod`wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the definition of a pod is co-located containers. You can vertically scale them differently but there will always be exactly one of each per pod.

Comment: any `url` to explain this feature. Thanks for the swift reply.

Comment: What feature do you mean? What I said was just the literal definition of a pod.

Comment: ok thanks, so a pod will be created for each auto scale we do

Comment: If you are talking about using HPA then yes, that works by adjusting replica counts in response to metrics. This is why you should try and run only one primary “thing” per pod.